# How to convert string to hexadecimal integer in Python?

Tags: python, integer, hex

hi I get user argv from command line as follows: `'0x000aff00'`

and I want python to treat it as hex directly...

```
str = sys.argv[1]
```

how is it possible? thanks!

Comment: Do not make a variable name (`str`) that is the same as a data type (`str`).  It's a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try: `i = int(sys.argv[1], 16)`

Comment: Python never fails to amaze me

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    i = int(sys.argv[1], 16)
except Exception,e:
    print e
else:
    # carry on
```